# Azure Web Deployment Database Connection Problems

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, azure

I've created an application using the ASP.Net Entity Framework 6 Code First approach. 
The app runs fine locally, using a local instance of a SQL Server database. 
After creating an azure account and publishing the site to the Azure service, the site home page and login pages load just fine. 
If I try to login or access the 'register' page, I get the following exception:

> Cannot open server "app.co.za" requested by the login.  The login
>   failed.

app.co.za is not the real domain name, I have replaced the original. 
The original domain is only related to the site because I've created my Azure account using my email from that domain. 
When specifying the Azure database under the deployment profile in Visual Studio, I entered the connection string provided on the Azure Portal with my Azure portal login details (which is where I think the issue might be).

Since this is a login issue though, I'm not sure if I've entered the correct set of credentials? I've made sure that there are no errors in the password.

How can I know that I have used the correct credentials to log in with?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try to open your database from Sql Server Management Studio (or any other client) and see if you're able to access. Also, make sure you authorize your client ip on the sql server firewall on azure portal.

Comment: Which azure service are you using, Azure web app? I would recommend you [Remote debugging web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) to narrow this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Databases are firewalled and only allow connections from whitelisted IP addresses. If you haven't already done so, please browse to your Azure SQL DB in the Azure Portal and click on the Overview tab. You'll then see a "Set Server Firewall" menu option on the Overview tab. Add your current IP address to the list.

You can verify that your IP is whitelisted by connecting to your Azure SQL DB via Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: I have added the firewall rule with the IP address as you specified for me, however I am still receiving the same error!